File pointer declaration interferes with a local variable in an unrelated function
So for an assignment I have to write a program that more or less plays scrabble, the basic structure is a function reads an input word, and counts how many times each letter appears in it into an array of ints with size 26. This allows the computer to compare that to the number of letters in the player hand, and normally, it works well:
//Define
void getLetterDistribution(char *word, int *dist){
 for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
  printf("%c",i+65);
 }
 printf("\n");
 for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
  int j = 0;
  do{
   if(word[j] == i+65){ //The capital letters begin at 65 in the ascii table
    dist[i]++; //Increase the count for that letter
   }
   j++;
  }while(word[j] != '\0'); //Wait for end of word
  printf("%d",dist[i]);
 }
 printf("%ls\n",dist);
}

//Call
void gameLoop(){
 char testHand[12] = "ACEROLAORIO\0"; //TEST INVOCATIONS
 int testHandDist[26];
 do{
  displayWorld();
  printf("Hand: %s\n",testHand);
  acceptInput();
  getLetterDistribution(testHand,handDist);
  getLetterDistribution(buffer,guessDist);
  printf("%d\n",compareCounts(guessDist,handDist));//TEST INVOCATIONS
 }while(isDone()!=1);
}

You can see here, the code for debugging purposes is printing out each element of the array in memory pointed to by the local variable dist after it finishes counting all the appearances of that letter into that array, underneath a line of the letters for reference. Probably not efficient but I'm a student. To meet the design specs of the assignment this function is then called in gameLoop() which will be called in the main() after init() and run exactly once (isDone() currently always returns 1, but will later be modified to be a win-loss checker)
--------------------------
Hand: ACEROLAORIO
Enter a Guess: core
CORE
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
20101000100100300200000000
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
00101000000000100100000000
1

You can see this console output I copied shows the player hand "ACEROLAORIO" letter distribution, followed by the letter distribution of the word "CORE". It also puts a "1" or "0" if the word you entered can be formed with your hand, using a function called compareCounts().
But now, it has to check the word against a dictionary to make sure it's valid, so literally all I did was add a declaration a file pointer to open the dictionary.txt to the init() function.
Before
int init(){
 srand(time(NULL));
 return 0;
}

After
int init(){
 srand(time(NULL));
 FILE* dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt","r");
 return 0; //Placeholder
}

New Output
--------------------------
Hand: ACEROLAORIO
Enter a Guess: core
CORE
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
-19329427032558-195148716325586984704112195269939371221952698470411219526993937122195369847041021952-195303658325580200405811584327644058118803276469846781321952
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
00101000000000100100000000
0

And now, while the submitted word is still producing a valid letter distribution, the player hand is producing nonsense and gibberish, which the comparator can't read.
The only difference between the two is that the submitted word's distribution array is declared as a global variable, whereas the player hand's distribution array is currently declared as a local variable in the gameLoop() function for testing purposes because I haven't written a function to randomize the player's hand yet.
I could patch this by declaring a the player hand's distribution array a global variable, but I want to know why this is happening, why the simple act of declaring a file pointer in another function is messing with this local variable, so I can avoid making this mistake again. Furthermore I suspect it's a problem with how I've designed the function's use of pointers, and proper pointer use is something the prof wants to make sure we learn.
The complete and unabridged source code is here: https://pastebin.com/hgJ8VhWs

Make a [MCVE] of code.

Looking at your full code, just how many letters are you putting into int guessDist[26];?

Aside: You don't need to put the \0 into a string literal explicitly, it's added automatically. And it's best to use char testHand[] to let it figure out the length automatically -- many bugs are due to using the wrong length.

What is the testHandDiff variable for? You never use it. Meanwhile you use a variable handDist that you never declare.

And the converse of what @Barmar said - you can't treat an array of char values as a string unless you know there's a terminating \0 character value...

The nested loops is a silly way to count all the characters. Just loop over the characters in the string, and then increment dist[word[j]-'A']. And don't hard-code ASCII values in your code, use character literals.

You most likely have a buffer overflow somewhere, which causes undefined behavior. This is usually indicated when you get different results due to adding innocuous changes like calling fopen().

Thanks for the good practice tips, I'll definitely make those improvements too. The overflow makes sense, but is there a better way I could protect against it than just globalizing? Is globalizing even protecting it or just hiding it?
EDIT: A lot of the empty stuff is reserved for future developement/construction which is why i only included the relevant functions

Sorry just to clarify, handDist is declared as a global. testHandDist is a local. when I pass the global in the function calls, it works, when i pass the local, it produces the buffer overflow.

Why not just loop over word and fill dist? E.g., for (int i = 0; word[i]; i++) { dist[word[i]-65]++; } That's all you need to populate the dist frequency-array. (you should also validate all characters are upper-case -- or convert them to upper-case)

No, global vs local wouldn't be the cause of the bug.  As you say, changing it to global would just mask it.  This would be a good opportunity to learn to use memory debugging tools like AddressSanitizer, valgrind, etc, which can catch the invalid memory access right where it occurs, rather than leaving you to just notice some corruption later.

Turn on compiler warnings, too.  I get one immediately on if (buffer != NULL).  The array you passed can't become null.  You have to check the return value from fgets.

The issue from your pastebin clearly indicates your problem is not buffer overlow but use of unitialized variables. Also next time if you have to post external link to some code use Godbolt instead of pastebin. Anyway, you should learn what a [mre] is and post the MRE as is in the body of your question. In general, you shouldn't need any globals, especially for such a simple program.

getLetterDistribution seems to assume that the dist array it's passed is initialized to all zeros.  That's true for global objects by default, but not for locals unless they are explicitly initialized.
The contents of an uninitialized local object are "garbage", and often this garbage is dependent on how stack memory is used by other parts of the program.  So if you're reading uninitialized data, it's not surprising that unrelated changes to the program would change its behavior.
You can initialize testHandDist with int testHandDist[26] = { 0 };.  (If you explicitly initialize any elements of an array, the rest are all automatically initialized to 0.)
However, instead you probably want to change getLetterDistribution to set every element of the dist array to 0 before starting; after all, getLetterDistribution knows what it needs, and the programmer shouldn't be expected to remember that every time they call it. Note that as it stands, even with a global handDist you would still have a bug if your loop iterated more than once, because on the second iteration handDist wouldn't be all zeros anymore.
